# Ruby: how does running this block through instance_eval work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently seen some code that I do not completely understand. There is an array named `foo` that contains instances of `Proc` objects. Then, an env object is used to setup an environment to work in:

```
env = Object.new
foo.each do |f|
    env.instance_eval &f # what happens here?
end
```

What exactly happens when you open the object with instance_eval and pass `&f` as an argument? What happens to env at this point and the Proc itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Proc gets executed in the context of `env`. It is as if you are calling a method on `env`: the block has access to its instance variables and public and private methods.

```
env = Object.new

env.instance_variable_set :@test, "test"

class << env
  private
  def test
    @test
  end
end

env.instance_eval { @test } #=> "test"
env.instance_eval { test }  #=> "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope is changed for the proc, which is then evaluated in that context. Internally, all procs are stored in memory as a C `struct` which includes the `self` of the proc (the scope in which the proc was made). When you call `instance_eval`, the `self` value is manually changed in memory to the object you are calling `instance_eval` on. If you explore the ruby source code, you will find that it boils down to this function:

```
static VALUE
yield_under(VALUE under, VALUE self, VALUE values)
{
    rb_thread_t *th = GET_THREAD();
    rb_block_t block, *blockptr;
    NODE *cref;

    if ((blockptr = GC_GUARDED_PTR_REF(th->cfp->lfp[0])) != 0) {
    block = *blockptr;
    block.self = self; // <- This is where the scope changes!
    th->cfp->lfp[0] = GC_GUARDED_PTR(&block);
    }
    cref = vm_cref_push(th, under, NOEX_PUBLIC, blockptr);
    cref->flags |= NODE_FL_CREF_PUSHED_BY_EVAL;

    if (values == Qundef) {
    return vm_yield_with_cref(th, 1, &self, cref);
    }
    else {
    return vm_yield_with_cref(th, RARRAY_LENINT(values), RARRAY_PTR(values), cref);
    }
}
```

Note the line containing `// <- This is where the scope changes!`.